# SQL - using a variable for an IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to do something like the following:

```
declare @FrameNumber nvarchar(20)
set @FrameNumber = '(p1, p2)'

select from myTable where c1 in @FrameNumber
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

(for note: I need to pass the value of @FrameNumber in as a parameter to the stored procedure... so I have to at least use the string "p1, p2")

would prefure and answer that was SQL 7 compatible, but SQL 2005 would be sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

```
DECLARE @FrameNumbers TABLE (code NVARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT
INTO   @framenumbers
VALUES ('p1')

INSERT
INTO   @framenumbers
VALUES ('p2')

SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   c1 IN
        (
        SELECT  code
        FROM    @framenumbers
        )
```

Comment: I need to pass the value of @FrameNumber in as a parameter to the stored procedure... so I have to use the string "p1, p2"

Comment: In `SQL Server 2008`, you can do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_ParseStringToTable] (@stringIN varchar(2000)) 
RETURNS @tOUT TABLE(RoomID int) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @pos int
SET @pos=CHARINDEX(',',@StringIN)
WHILE @pos>0
     BEGIN
     INSERT @tOUT(RoomID) SELECT LEFT(@StringIN,CHARINDEX(',',@StringIN)-1)
     SET @stringIN = SUBSTRING(@StringIN,CHARINDEX(',',@StringIN)+1,LEN(@StringIN))
     SET @pos=CHARINDEX(',',@StringIN)
     END
IF LEN(@StringIN)>0
     BEGIN
     INSERT @tOUT(RoomID) SELECT @StringIN
     END
RETURN 
END
```

usage...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (func_ParseStringToTable(@ids))
```

Comment: 'func_ParseStringToTable' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @alumb, right, it's a custom function.  The script above creates it.

Answer (score 1):

You could put load those values into a table variable, or you could use dynamic sql.  Here are examples of each:

### TABLE VARIABLE

```
DECLARE @FrameNumbers TABLE (
    Frame NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @FrameNumbers (
    Frame
)
SELECT 'p1'
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2'
```

option 1:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE c1 in (
    SELECT Frame
    FROM @FrameNumbers
)
```

option 2:

```
SELECT
    m.*
FROM myTable m
INNER JOIN @FrameNumbers f ON f.Frame = m.c1
```

All that is fine, but this is my favorite:

### DYNAMIC SQL

```
DECLARE 
@FrameNumber nvarchar(20),
@sql nvarchar(max),
@ParamDef nvarchar(1000)

SET @FrameNumber = '(p1, p2)'

SET @sql = N'SELECT FROM myTable WHERE c1 IN ' + @FrameNumber

EXECUTE dbo.sp_ExecuteSQL @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution to do with split function,

```
DECLARE @FrameNumber NVARCHAR(20)
SET @FrameNumber = 'p1,p2'

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ProductCode IN 
(SELECT Value FROM fn_Split(@FrameNumber, ','))
```

**OutPut:**

[image]

**Split Functions:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_Split (
    @String VARCHAR(8000)
    ,@Delimiter CHAR(1)
    )
RETURNS @temptable TABLE (Value VARCHAR(8000))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idx INT
    DECLARE @slice VARCHAR(8000)

    SELECT @idx = 1

    IF len(@String) < 1
        OR @String IS NULL
        RETURN

    WHILE @idx != 0
    BEGIN
        SET @idx = charindex(@Delimiter, @String)

        IF @idx != 0
            SET @slice = left(@String, @idx - 1)
        ELSE
            SET @slice = @String

        IF (len(@slice) > 0)
            INSERT INTO @temptable (Value)
            VALUES (@slice)

        SET @String = right(@String, len(@String) - @idx)

        IF len(@String) = 0
            BREAK
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

what version of SQL Server ?

If you are in 2008 you might be able to use table datatypes. Simplifies these things a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sql Server 2005+ have a look at this

```
--Split
DECLARE @textXML XML
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @delimiter NVARCHAR(5)

SELECT  @data = 'A,B,C',
        @delimiter = ','

SELECT    @textXML = CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(@data, @delimiter, '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML)
SELECT  T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS data
FROM    @textXML.nodes('/d') T(split)
```

You can you that as your in table to select from.

Have a look at [XML Support in Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

final solution:

```
DECLARE @FrameNumbers TABLE (FrameNumber NVARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY)

DECLARE @pos int
SET @pos=CHARINDEX(',',@FrameNumber)
WHILE @pos>0 BEGIN
     INSERT @FrameNumbers SELECT LEFT(@FrameNumber,CHARINDEX(',',@FrameNumber)-1)
     SET @FrameNumber = SUBSTRING(@FrameNumber,CHARINDEX(',',@FrameNumber)+1,LEN(@FrameNumber))
     SET @pos=CHARINDEX(',',@FrameNumber)
END
IF LEN(@FrameNumber)>0 BEGIN
     INSERT @FrameNumbers SELECT @FrameNumber
END

select from myTable where c1 in (select FrameNumber from @FrameNumbers)
```

thanks Quassnoi and Sam, this solution is just a combination of your solutions.